# Android - Application Launch test

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, performance-testing

I am creating an app that will launch the various android apps(i.e: Contacts, Calendar, Email...) and record its launch time.

For this I have the following code.

```html
public class LaunchPerformanceBase extends InstrumentationTestCase {

public static final String LOG_TAG = "Launch Perf";

public Bundle mResults;
public Intent mIntent;

public LaunchPerformanceBase(String pkg_name, String class_name) {
    mResults = new Bundle();
    try {
        mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        mIntent.setClassName("com.android.contacts.activities", "com.android.contacts.activities.PeopleActivity");
        mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "NULL POINTER EXCEPTION setClassName()");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * Launches intent, and waits for idle before returning.
 *
 */
public void LaunchApp() {
    try {
        Activity act = getInstrumentation().startActivitySync(mIntent); <-- LINE NUMBER 69
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
        act.finish();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And from the main app, i am doing the following.

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                LaunchPerformanceBase LaunchData = new LaunchPerformanceBase("com.google.android.contacts", "com.android.contacts.activities.PeopleActivity");
                LaunchData.LaunchApp(); <--LINE NUMBER 38
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    thread.start();
}
```

I am getting a NullPointerException at startActivitySync() call.
01-05 08:55:59.430    4653-4692/perftest.com.applicationlaunchtime W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.Activity android.app.Instrumentation.startActivitySync(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
01-05 08:55:59.430    4653-4692/perftest.com.applicationlaunchtime W/System.err﹕ at perftest.com.applicationlaunchtime.LaunchPerformanceBase.LaunchApp(LaunchPerformanceBase.java:69)
01-05 08:55:59.430    4653-4692/perftest.com.applicationlaunchtime W/System.err﹕ at perftest.com.applicationlaunchtime.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:38)

I am new to Android app development, so any help with this very much appreciated.

Comment: @OP Let me know if my answer below helps your or not. If not comment below I would be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a null pointer exception because  this code

```
public Intent mIntent;
```

The scope of this variable `mIntent` is throughout the `LaunchPerformanceBase` class.

In the constructor  `public LaunchPerformanceBase(String pkg_name, String class_name)` you have initialized intent with the same name as above,

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
```

When you call `startActivitySync(mIntent);` in your `LaunchApp()`, it is referring to the `public Intent mIntent;`variable which is declared above not initialized. That is the reason you are getting an Null pointer exception.

So change this line of code ,

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
```

to

```
mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. I have tried that and I am still getting the same error.    <pre> <code> W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.Activity android.app.Instrumentation.startActivitySync(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
W/System.err﹕ at perftest.com.applicationlaunchtime.LaunchPerformanceBase.LaunchApp(LaunchPerformanceBase.java:91)
W/System.err﹕ at perftest.com.applicationlaunchtime.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:68)

Comment: @JackupPeter - `LaunchPerformanceBase.java:89, MainActivity.java:67, MainActivity.java:66` -  Can you point out these lines in your code ?? Also Please save your program everytime  before you compile or else your old code only will be compiled.

Comment: **LaunchPerformanceBase.java:89:** Activity act = getInstrumentation().startActivitySync(mIntent); **MainActivity.java:66:** LaunchPerformanceBase LaunchData = new LaunchPerformanceBase("com.google.android.contacts", "com.android.contacts.activities.PeopleActivity"); **MainActivity.java:67:** LaunchData.LaunchApp();

Comment: I don't have enough points to chat there, you will need at least 20 points to chat.

Comment: @JackupPeter All your errors are pointing at this part of the code `getInstrumentation().startActivitySync(mIntent);`

Comment: @JackupPeter Yeah just now realized, Can you edit your question with the latest code you tried and the stacktrace too ? Also Please indicate the lines in question too